# Python calling super constructor - am I doing it right?

Tags: python, coding-style, dry

I have a base class like so:

```
class Token:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value.strip()
        self.tokens = None

    def get_value(self):
        return self.value

    def tokenize(self):
        pass # abstract stub

    def __str__(self):
        return type(self).__name__ + ': '+ re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', self.value)
```

And a ton of it's child classes:

```
class T_DefineDirective(Token):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__(value)


class T_IncludeDirective(Token):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__(value)


class T_IfdefDirective(Token):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__(value)


class T_Identifier(Token):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__(value)


class T_Rvalue(Token):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__(value)

    def tokenize(self):
        pass # stuff here
```

Now I'm a DRY programmer. I hate repetition. If you look at the code, the `__init__` piece is copy-pasted in all the child classes.

My question, is there some way to avoid the repetition, or is this really the right way?

*(note that the example is a bit shortened, so it may not make too much sense. But you can see the issue I mean).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not have any additional setup work to do in the `Token` subclasses, then it is safe not to override `__init__`.

If you do have to perform some subclass-specific initialisation, then the patten that you're using is fine and 'pythonic'.

---

To clarify:

- if `__init__` is not defined on a class, then Python will use the `__init__` method defined on (one of) its parent class(es), if possible

  - this is because there aren't any special rules for overriding 'magic' methods like `__init__`
- even if the initialiser on a parent class is used, an instance of the subclass will be created

  - this is because the actual creation happens in `__new__`; the newly created object is then passed to `__init__` for initialisation

Comment: you mean, if the child class is missing `__init__`, the parent's `__init__` is used instead?

Comment: @MightyPork - yes, `__init__` (and other special methods) are inherited in the same way as normal python methods.

Comment: oh cool, didn't know this, thx. So.. I just put `pass` in the classes now?

Comment: @MightyPork - You can just leave the `__init__` method undefined.  Python will still create an instance of the subclass, even if the superclass `__init__` is what is called (this is because creation happens in `__new__`, before initialisation)

Comment: @sapi: He's saying that the classes will have no methods at all, so they class itself will need a `pass` to be valid syntax. Which is right.

Comment: Nice explanation. Of course he's not defining `__new__` in either `Token` _or_ the subclasses, but that's OK because `object.__new__` gets the class object for the class you're trying to create and knows how to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to eliminate as much boilerplate as possible:

First, you don't need `__init__` if all it does is call `super()`; special methods are inherited just like any other methods, as sapi's answer explains.

Second, you can dynamically create a bunch of classes:

```
token_classes = {
    'T_{}'.format(name): type('T_{}'.format(name), (Token,), {})
    for name in 'DefineDirective IncludeDirective IfdefDirective Identifier'.split()
}
```

And you can use them straight out of that dict, but if you really want to make them into globals you can:

```
globals().update(token_classes)
```

However, the whole goal of avoiding repetition is to make your code more readable and maintainable, and in this case, I think we're achieving the opposite. :)

Comment: I think I'll stick with the traditional approach for readability, but this is still an interesting technique.

Comment: @MightyPork: This gets more fun when you have methods, descriptors, or class variables (they go inside the empty dict) or a metaclass (it goes in place of `type`) and you're building the classes dynamically. For creating simple static classes, it's pretty silly.